# Variadic template constructor priority

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following simple `struct`

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
   A(T a) {}

   template <typename ... Ts>
   A(T a, Ts ... more) {}
};

int main()
{
   A<int> a(1);
}
```

What is the guarantee that `A(T a)` will be called instead of the variadic template constructor, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The section in the standard you're looking for is §14.8.2.4

> If A was transformed from a function parameter pack and P is not a parameter pack, type deduction fails. Otherwise, using the resulting types P and A, the deduction is then done as described in 14.8.2.5. If P
>   is a function parameter pack, the type A of each remaining parameter type of the argument template is
>   compared with the type P of the declarator-id of the function parameter pack. Each comparison deduces
>   template arguments for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by the function
>   parameter pack. If deduction succeeds for a given type, the type from the argument template is considered
>   to be at least as specialized as the type from the parameter template.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class... Args> void f(Args... args); // #1
> template<class T1, class... Args> void f(T1 a1, Args... args); // #2
> template<class T1, class T2> void f(T1 a1, T2 a2); // #3
> f(); // calls #1
> f(1, 2, 3); // calls #2
> f(1, 2); // calls #3; non-variadic template #3 is more
> // specialized than the variadic templates #1 and #2
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: 14.8.2.4 is about comparing two function templates to see which is more specialized.  But one of the candidate functions in this example is not a function template at all.

Comment: @aschepler You're saying that the compiler does not have to get this far, because having a non-template function which is a perfect match means it does not even need to begin template resolution. I agree. There will be another section which covers this.

Answer (score 2):

The same reason `f(const int&)` is a better match than `f(const T&)` when `T` can be deduced as `int`: `A(int)` is a non-template function and `A(int, Ts...)` with `Ts...` deduced as the empty list is a function template specialization.